# I need something like "skipifdoesntexist" within [Files] section in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I need something like "skipifdoesntexist" within `[Files]` section, so that if (external) file simply does not exist - skip it without showing an error message.

How to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean when the source file does not exist?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to work with external file using {src}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`skipifsourcedoesntexist` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=skipifsourcedoesntexist):

> This flag instructs the compiler -- or Setup, if the `external` flag is also used -- to silently skip over the entry if the source file does not exist, instead of displaying an error message.

Comment: so I should use `skipifsourcedoesntexist external`?

Comment: Sure, you want both flags.